# How to handle unlimited/unknown number of columns in Google Sheets using formuals

Tags: google-sheets, automation, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have several Google Sheets with an unknown number of rows and columns. The number of rows and columns are the same(all are 20x20 or 100x100).

Now I want to sum them together. Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1+Sheet3!A1 and so on for all the cells.

Is there a way to do it using formulas and do it automatically? the contents in those sheets are generated automatically.

I thought of two arrayformulas like
ARRAYFORMULA((ARRAYFORMULA())
but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Your ideas or solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A1:T20 + Sheet2!A1:T20 + Sheet3!A1:T20)
```

if rows are unknown you can use:

```
={A1:A}
```

if columns are unknown you can use:

```
={A1:1}
```

combined you can try:

```
={A1:1000}
```

in some cases you may use:

```
=INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), COLUMNS(1:1)))
```

for another sheet it needs to be:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:"&ADDRESS(ROWS(Sheet2!A:A), COLUMNS(Sheet2!1:1)))
```

also you should note that ranges needs to be of equal size when summing them up